# Vue.js - why root element can not have the v-for and needs div wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I am seeking an explanation of why I need the main wrapping div in this template in Vue. Without it, if the main element is the div with `v-for` - then listing of items stops working.

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="devlistitem">
<div><div class="item" v-for="item in cd_items">
    <div v-if="!item.u" class="heade">{{ item.p }}</div>
<div v-if="item.desc" class="desc">{{ item.desc }}</div>
  </div></div>
  </script>

<script>// component
Vue.component('devlistitems', { 
  props: ['dataitems']
  , computed: { cd_items: function () { 
   var x = this.dataitems; return APP_DATA[x];  }
  } 
  , template:'#devlistitem'}
);</script>
```

Data are defined right in source, no ajax, and in main app I simply use a component with a property telling which data to use:

```
<devlistitems dataitems="json_items" />
```

Meaning to use `APP_DATA['json_items']` as source data. Everything works ok, but removing the outer div makes it stop working.

Comment: and second - the root element does not let me replace it with <template> instead of <div> - sstops working again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element

> Every component must have a single root element

As a sample from the site, this will not work

```
<h3>{{ title }}</h3>
<div v-html="content"></div>
```

To fix you can do some thing like:

```
<div class="blog-post">
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  <div v-html="content"></div>
</div>
```

---

You need to re-design this component.
The component manages the for `loop internally`. You can have a dumb component that only shows one `item`. The parent loops and shows `item`.

Again have a look at`blog-post` sample at the https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element

Comment: u mean if it has a v-for it cant be root? right? it still is a single div, just the v-for for iteration....

Comment: @Peminator yes. But I think you need to re-design this component. You component manages the `for loop internally`. You can have a dumb component that only shows item. The parent loops and shows item. Again see `blog-post` sample at the https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element.

Comment: @Peminator good to hear that. i update the answer to help others too.

Comment: @Peminator please mark it as correct answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Template can have only one root element.V-for returns multiple root elements, so it's necessary to enclose it inside an element.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: and it cant be a <template> root ? thats a bit limiting imho, but im a beginner, sure i do something wrong

Comment: but your explanation of the v-for was clear, thanks at least for that, a lot

Comment: Yes, also you can not have a `<template>` tag as a root, at least in single file components it doesn't work. I suppose it's because in that case you would have two nested 'templates', but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Vue can only have A Single Root Element
Error:

```
<div><p>Text</p></div>
<div><p>Text2</p></div>
```

Correct:

```
<div>
 <div><p>Text</p></div>
 <div><p>Text2</p></div>
</div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element